# Applying weights to a Pandas Dataframe to identify recurring terms

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, n-gram, weighted-average

I have a very large Pandas Dataframe with a list of terms found in a large library of text. The columns are the term and the amount of times that term appears in the text:

```
Term                  Hits

volvo car handbrake   300
kelly blue book       20000
mcdonals health       1
dog show cambridge    50
..........
```

My aim is to do N-gram analysis on this file to identify the n-grams with the largest amount of activity. But I want it sorted by HOW MUCH activity an n-gram has appeared in the text body. e.g. I am more interested in n-grams that commonly appear in terms in the 20000+ Hits range than those that mostly appear in terms that have only a few Hits.

With this in mind, I think some form of weighted analysis needs to be done here. Is their some form of functionality in Pandas or Sklearn that would help me accomplish this?

I have a basic CountVectorizer example that I have used for n-gram analysis up until now but it may not apply in this case.

```
df = pd.read_csv('terms.csv', names=['Keyword'])

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3, 3), analyzer='word', stop_words='english')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Keyword'])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).data
output_df = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
output_df = output_df.sort_values('frequency', ascending=False)
output_df.to_csv('analysis_output.csv')
```

**EDIT:**

I suppose another way to think of this is that the Hits column is essentially a weights column in of itself. As such, what I am looking for is a way to add the amount of times a term appears to the frequency an n-gram contained in that term would appear in my document.

Comment: Do you want frequency of ngrams to be atleast 20000+?

Comment: 20000 is really a ball-park estimate I went with for the sample above. I would prefer the final output to consider ALL of the terms. But if you have an idea that relies on some minimum value, I would still like to hear it.

Comment: Once you get the weights, won't `pd.multiply` do?

Comment: @GreenGodot in response to your second comment: you can bootstrap your samples. Randomly draw sample size of `n` from the `Hits`column, compute `min`on bootstrapped samples. Repeat this 100 times and construct your confidence intervals. This was you can get a distribution of `min` in your samples and then simply choose the mean of this distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I had written these functions earlier for generating `ngrams` and finding there frequency:

```
import nltk

def generate_ngrams(text, n_gram=2):
    token = [token for token in text.strip().lower().split(" ")]
    ngrams = zip(*[token[i:] for i in range(n_gram)])
    return [" ".join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]

def ngram_freq(column, topn = 50, min_count = None, n_gram = 2):
    ngrams = [ngram for text in column for ngram in generate_ngrams(text, n_gram)]
    if min_count is None:
        return sorted(nltk.FreqDist(ngrams).items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)[:topn]
    else:
        return [(x,y) for x,y in  nltk.FreqDist(ngrams).items() if y>=min_count]
#         return sorted(nltk.FreqDist(ngrams).items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)[:topn]

generate_ngrams('This is an Example')
> ['this is', 'is an', 'an example']

generate_ngrams('This is an Example', n_gram=3)
> ['this is an', 'is an example']
```

The ngram_freq will return a tuple with the ngram and its frequency, depending on the parameters that are passed:

```
text_list = ['I am StackOverflow', 'I am StackOverflow not really',
            'Example Statement for StackOverflow',
            'Statement for StackOverflow']

ngram_freq(text_list, min_count=2)

> [('i am', 2),
 ('am stackoverflow', 2),
 ('statement for', 2),
 ('for stackoverflow', 2)]
```

It can also return the top_n counts:

```
ngram_freq(text_list, topn=2)
> [('i am', 2), ('am stackoverflow', 2)]
```

So for your case, you can pass the column(`df['keyword']`) to the `ngram_freq` function, and add `min_count` parameter as 20000 and `ngram` can be whatever you prefer.